# Google Maps integration into website

Tags: google-maps

I want to make a web application that will get 2 location and their postalcode and show the result on google map. For example, I select 2 cities or a country and show the road map with a colored line according to my points.

Answer (score 3):

Best place to look is the Google Maps API V3 Documentation - I recommend V3 as they don't support V2 anymore

Main documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Samples: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html

Simple directions sample: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple.html

Basically you need to have the two co-ordinates, although you can use street addresses, and pass that to the API and it goes off to google gets the results and then plots it. Easy as pie!

Comment: i am very thank full to you for your answer. if you send me a code i am intigrate in my code and done modification as per my requirements. i am see your last link its totly related to my question but i am add more locations and its attach with my application.   best regards

Comment: one thing else the map size is so large we require a 3 by 3 inch

Comment: With regard to the map size you can just put it in a div which has it's style width and height set. eg. <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100px;height:100px"></div>

Answer (score 2):

**Save this code as location.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Geolocation</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <link href="map.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<!--
Include the maps javascript with sensor=true because this code is using a
sensor (a GPS locator) to determine the user's location.
See: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#SpecifyingSensor
--> 
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(37.625364,-122.423905);

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:19,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: siberia,
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
        });

  var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: siberia,
    map: map,
    title: "omt"
  });
  map.setCenter(siberia);

}
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

**Save this code as map.css**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

#map_canvas {
height: 650px;
}
}
```